# Clarification about using form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

While creating a search form I am facing a problem. I am getting the following error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

This is my view file:

"datepicker" %>

This is my clients_controller.rb:

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  def newClients
  end
end
```

And this is my model client.rb:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

I am confused in using `form_for` parameter. Can any one explain it briefly how and why to use `form_for` parameter?

**Edit 1**

I have modified my controller as

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  def search
      redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Once i click submit button it showing error as

```
No route matches [GET] "/search"
```

Comment: `def newClients
 @client = Client.new  end` in your controller you are not define @client but in view you are using it...and one more thing please follo rails naming convention the method name should be `new_clients` or 'new`

Comment: How can i do it for search

Comment: If i give data of birth and submit form it should list all users who having same data of birth.

Comment: then add a method in controller `def search @results = User.where('created_at = ?', params[:bithday].to_datetime) end`

Comment: Ok ill add a method in controller as search but how to mention it in my form_for

Comment: If you want to search you should **not** use `form_for`. You should just use `form_tag`. `form_for` should be used when creating or updating records. You're not doing that, so `form_tag` is a better fit.

Comment: ook ok ...got it ...<%form_for search_clients_path do |f|%>`...give me your application I can set it up.....here it is very hard to write all codes

Comment: [Here's an example of a search form using `form_tag` instead of `form_for`.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#a-generic-search-form)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing something here. Let me explain.

In your controller you don't need to define a custom method (called `newClients`) since Rails conventions suggest to use the following:

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /clients
  def index
    @clients = Client.all
  end

  # GET /clients/:id    
  def show
    @client = Client.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /clients/new
  def new
    @client = Client.new
  end

  # POST /clients
  def create
    @client = Client.new(params[:client])
    if @client.save
      redirect_to :back, success: "Successfully created..."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # GET /clients/:id/edit
  def edit
    @client = Client.find(params[:id])
  end

  # PUT /clients/:id
  def update
    @client = Client.find(params[:id])
    if @client.update_attributes(params[:client])
      redirect_to :back, success: "Successfully edited..."
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  # DELETE /clients/:id
  def destroy
    @client = Client.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to :back, success: "Successfully deleted..."
  end
end
```

And finally, in order for your `form_for` to work properly, you need to pass it an instance of a class:

```
form_for @client
```

where `@client` is `Client.new` in your case.

Comment: Rails doesn't provide you with these methods. It only does so when you use scaffold, but there is no sign of that in the question. Besides, he wants to search, not create, update or delete.

Comment: Yes, but he's not doing a create, update or delete. The only relevant one maybe `index`. It's not a crime to create your own methods in a controller though.

Comment: That's the solution to get rid of the error, but it doesn't answer the question IMO.

Comment: The question is *why* and how. The why part is completely missing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in your controller please follow Rails naming conventions. The method name should be `new_clients` or `new`.

```
def new
  @client = Client.new
end
```

Your view name should be new.html.erb.

You are not defining `@client` in your controller, but in the view you are using it.